# What should be the security context of these cron files?

Tags: cron, selinux, fedora

I am running Fedora 20 and I am having some issues when running logrotate and anacron which I suspect may be related to SELinux:

```
Failed to determine timestamp: Cannot assign requested address
chgrp: changing group of /var/log/mariadb: Permission denied
```

I did some research and came across this article from [Gentoo wiki](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/cron) that says the following:

> If you want to perform system administrative tasks using cronjobs, you
>   will need to take special care that the domain in which the job runs
>   has sufficient privileges.
>
> First, make sure that your cronjobs run in the system_cronjob_t
>   domains. This means that the cronjobs must be defined as either
>
> ```
> scripts in the /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily, ... directories
> crontab entries in the /etc/cron.d directory
> crontab entries in the /etc/crontab file
> ```

A check on my SELinux default policies reveals that I have the following instead:

```
/etc/cron.daily(/.*)?    all files      system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 
/etc/cron.hourly(/.*)?   all files      system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 
/etc/cron.monthly(/.*)?  all files      system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 
/etc/cron.weekly(/.*)?   all files      system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 
/etc/cron\.d(/.*)?       all files      system_u:object_r:system_cron_spool_t:s0 
/etc/crontab             regular file   system_u:object_r:system_cron_spool_t:s0
```

Should I change the SELinux policy to so that these have `system_cronjob_t` as the context label instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is how it should be:

From changelog of selinux-policy-3.12.1-139:

> - Allow systemd_cronjob_t to be entered via bin_t

Do you have any errors in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` pertaining to `mariadb`?  A quick and easy check is to `setenforce=0` and run your `cron` jobs.  If they fare better then it was SELinux causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you. I do have SELinux error pertaining to logrotate trying to set permission on mariadb log files in one script. After perusing the permissions again, I find that I have context label `etc_t` for my crontab file, which could be the cause of all these problems. Will review it next week when that particular cron job is activated again.